# Mobile Display Full Page on Initial Load

Tags: html, css, mobile, mobile-safari

URL: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/94440365/mobile/static.html

When viewing this page on iPhone, the initial view will zoom into the page as follows:
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/94440365/mobile/iphone.jpg

The viewport I am using is:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

I have tried a number of viewport options but I can't seem to prevent this initial zoom. I've read through some great articles (stackoverflow prevents me from adding more than 2 links so I can't link to it here.)

Please help with any suggestions.

Comment: You have a few HTML errors... can you fix them and see if that helps? Also, does removing `initial-scale=1.0` change anything?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The HTML errors have been fixed and initial-scale=1.0 has been removed. Doesn't seem to have an impact.

Comment: Not sure what else to try?

Comment: I'm completely stuck with this. Any other options?